# Java android fullscreen flag problem, How can i make notch/in-screen camera type phones full screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

notch/in-screen camera type phones how can i make full screen  [this type phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwe9y.png)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

also my styles.xml both day night and dark theme same no action bar.

```
 <style name="Theme.InEnemies" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`
```

this is my main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".init.MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

size of this black bar suggests that this is `ActionBar` or `Toolbar`, so your app is already fullscreen and this is part of your GUI. you may try to hide it by styling properly your `Activity` (`.NoActionBar` suffix styles) or by code `getSupportActionBar().hide()`/`getActionBar().hide()` (depends on AndroidX/AppCompat presence). would be easier to guess if you would post XML of an `Activity`s layout (`R.layout.activity_main` file) and `style` set to this `Activity` in manifest

btw. thats my way for making `Activity` full screen in dynamic way during `Activity`s runtime

```
public void setFullscreen(boolean enabled) {
    int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    uiOptions = enabled ?
            // include some flags
            (uiOptions
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) :
            // exclude them
            (uiOptions
                    & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

this will work also with devices with notch/in-screen camera

Comment: @Kheseyroon Update in your question

Comment: okey i found that that problem happening in android emulator devices when i try to run on physical devices it works now the problem notch/in screen phone still there is black camera line.

Comment: check [THIS](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout) doc, you probably shuld use `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following flags, also I do not think you need to do anything different for those types of phone specifically.

```java
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your style.xml
For example, here is mine

`<style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">`

1. You should take yours and change the last part in `NoActionBar` as I did.
2. Insert items inside, it depends on what you need. For example:

   ```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   ```

Then, if it isn't enough, put this code in your activities:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

You can also try to set it transparent. In your style:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Then, in your root Layout of Activity:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: i have already made noactionbar but i tried what you suggest its not working same problem continues

Comment: Edited, try new answer.

Comment: still same nothing changed.

Comment: Are you setting it in the right style.xml? You should have one for your light theme, one for dark theme. Depending on what you are using, you should modify them both.

Answer (score 0):

Do it Simply Like this :

```
public void hideSystemUI() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY // hide status bar and nav bar after a short delay, or if the user interacts with the middle of the screen
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```